# MPI Java under windows

Tags: java, windows, api, mpi

Ive been working with MPI and OMP parallel solutions in C as an assignment to school.
I liked programming that way but im more into java.
I did a little research and found lots of wrappers and API's but all of them were quiet old.
So my question is whats the best "tool" for working with MPI OMP in java nowadays.
Im a win user.Just saying that becase i found some solutions which had poor windows support

thx in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most relevant and pain-less MPI Java implementations for you are: [FastMPJ](http://torusware.com/nevonproducts/fastmpj/) and [MPJ Express](http://mpj-express.org/). FastMPJ is a commercial product with free TCP/IP version whereas MPJ Express is an open source library.

Both have full support in Windows, as they are pure (non-wrapper) Java implementations. Both have extensive documentation on running on Windows, and using IDEs such as Eclipse, Netbeans and JCreator, check out their user's guide and documentation.

Comment: Thx for late answer. Menwhile i tested (not only) mentioned implementations and in case somebody is interested for me MPJExpress is the best choice. Great documentation easy working nice example files